# HP laptop HDD write behavior--is this normal? (Multiple files selected but simultaneous writes)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, copy

I currently use an HP laptop with i7-7700HQ and GTX 1050 with internal 256GB Samsung SSD (MZVLW2560H1Q1TB) and 1TB HGST HDD (HTS721010A9E630J).

The weird thing I see  is that whenever I select multiple files and copy them from SSD to internal HDD, the speed shoots up to 1GB/s and drops down to 100MB/s (fig. a). Finding this rather abnormal, I checked the Resource Monitor and it shows that the files I selected are being written all at the same time.

Is this normal to happen? I'm more concerned for the lifespan of the hard disk since the heads inside will have to move back and fourth endlessly whenever I copy multiple files at once.

Initial 1GB/s speed:

> [image]

Clearly multiple files selected at once, but simultaneous writes on Resmon?

> [image: Images]

Comment: I am not a Windows user (you are using Windows, correct?) but in my experience the guestimation that happens when multiple files are copied always shoots up at the beginning and then settles down to a slower speed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your comment! Yes, I'm using Windows. Guess then this may just be a normal behavior?